# How to write Mongo query to find data between dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to get data of owner ID which lies between two dates using datePicker.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5">
                    <label>From</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="date.from" name="datefrom"  /> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5">
                    <label>To</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="date.to" name="dateto"  /> </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary " ng-click="getleaddate()">Go</button>
                </div>
                
            </form>
```

**Node API**

```
apiRoutes.post('/getleaddate', function(req, res){
  var token=getToken(req.headers);
  var owner=jwt.decode(token, config.secret); 
    Lead.find({ownerId:owner._id},date:{$gte :new Date(req.body.datefrom), $lte:new Date(req.body.dateto)},function(err, data){
    if(err){res.json(err)}
      else{
        res.json(data);
        console.log(data)  
      }
      
  });
});
```

Above API is not working because `req.body.datefrom` and `req.body.dateto`  is `undefined`
I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the function for ng-click="getleaddate()"

Check the network tab on the request and request body sent  .

it is working fine for me :

```
FormData:

datefrom:2017-01-11
dateto:2017-01-04

router.post('/test', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.datefrom);
});
```

Console Output:

```
{ datefrom: '2017-01-11', dateto: '2017-01-04' }
```

Comment: I check Network tab following is in it kind
:
`"date"
message
:
"Cast to date failed for value "Invalid Date" at path "date""
name
:
"CastError"
path
:
"date"
value
:
null`

Comment: and my angular function is `$scope.getleaddate=function(){ 
  $http.post('/api/getleaddate', $scope.date).success(function(res){
    $scope.res=res;
  })
 }`

Comment: Yes... now console is showing value.... Before this I was checking `console.log(req.body.datefrom)` but its `undefined`. But instead I have write this `console.log(req.body.from)`. Thats why now console is printing the value... But query is not working.... for query I need to do this `date:{$gte :new Date("2017-01-01"), $lte:new Date("2017-01-05")` . To achieve this I am doing as `var from=req.body.from` and `var to=req.body.to` and query will be `date:{$gte :new Date("from"), $lte:new Date("to")` ... But Its not working... any solution for this??? plz

Comment: Date format supported new Date('Jan 08,2016'). find docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: but if I put static dates as  `2017-01-01` in query then its working fine.

Comment: check the bson type against the field. Is it still the Date bson type ?

Comment: Yes,...I have done, I have to convert input value in to string using `var datefrom=JSON.stringify(from);`. Now Query is working fine... Thanks